# How to cancel a payment that awaits confirmation in Metamask using web3?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, metamask, ethers.js

I'm working on a crypto payment system using ethers Web3Provider

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction(transactionObject)
```

After the user calls this method, this dialog is shown:
[image]

In the app the user is able to close the payment dialog leaving this pending. Is there a way to reject this payment using JS when closing the dialog inside the app? Clearing all payments would also be a solution but in the documentation I can't find anything about this case.

Comment: Hey!
Have you found a way to solve this problem?
I just have exactly the same situation now, I also need to cancel the pending transaction from js and close the Metamask popup.

Comment: I am curious too

Comment: Nope, cause there is none. A metamask dev commented on another site about how this is imposibile cause of the way web3 works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article that might help : https://chainstack.com/a-developers-guide-to-the-transactions-in-mempool-metamask-edition/

You can basically send a no eth transaction with a high fee and same account nounce as the pending transaction. This will help drop the pending transaction. This is how metamask "cancel" a transaction

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).